# TFS Manual Mstest Publish Results?

Tags: command-line, tfs, mstest, publish

Following a MSDN web page, I am trying to manually run mstest within my tfsbuild.proj and put the results into the pass/fail logic so the build will fail if this particular test fails. It's kind of like running a FxCop or something else from CMD and capturing a "0" or "1" and force-fail the build.

MSTest /testcontainer:test.dll /publish:http://ourtfsmachine:8080 /teamproject:ProjectName /publishbuild:BuildNumber01 /platform:AnyCpu /flavor:Release

I could understand running this inside an Exec task, butI don't know what the BuildNumber is, for example.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions for getting the Build Number from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243151%28VS.100%29.aspx:

1. Open Visual Studio and connect to a Team Foundation Server.
2. Open Team Explorer.
3. Open your team project and expand the team project node.
4. Under the build, double-click All Build Types or a specific build type to see its builds. Build names that you can use are in the Name column.